# Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

Tags: html, jquery, fine-uploader

I am using FineUpload plugin for Uploading file. I am able to see while rendering page But I am getting error message `Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)`. Due server is not returning valid JSON data that's why I am getting this Error. But I don't want to save my file on server side so dint written any code on server side. I just want to show that file on browser.

How I can achieve same.

Script:

```
<link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/5.16.2/fine-uploader-gallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/5.16.2/fine-uploader.min.js"></script>

<script>
        var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),
            template: 'qq-template-gallery',
            //request: {
            //    endpoint: '/server/uploads'
            //},
            
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Console window

[image: OutPut Screen]

[image: Network Tab]

Comment: That error generally means that the response is expected to be JSON, however the actual response was XML or HTML, usually due to an error message being returned instead of the expected data. Check the network tab in devtools to see what the actual response is. This should give you some information to debug in your server side code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I saw in network tab there i am getting `405 error method not allow`  why i am getting this error.  i don't want to wrte any code on server side how can i prevent this error

Comment: Method not allowed means that, in this case, the server does not accept a POST request to that endpoint. Perhaps try a GET as a test. If that's still not working check the code to see what the HTTP verb should be

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan from where i can change method from `POST to GET` Because i am not using server side code for FineUpload plugin could you please suggest me where i should change http verbs Please.

Comment: You're making the call to `localhost:1058/server/upload` so you need to amend the code being run on the server at that endpoint. If you have no server code, then you've misunderstood how file uploading works - you *have* to have some server side logic to receive the file and save it where necessary. See the FineUploader documentation for more information on that: https://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server.html